# Emacs window unexpectedly moves around using cygwin

Tags: emacs, window, cygwin

When I use Emacs 25.3 in Cygwin and XOrg on win10, the window moves around unexpectedly. If I snap the window to the left side of the screen and then open the minibuffer, the window slightly shifts, and covers part of the window on the right. This behavior does not happen with MS Windows Emacs. If there a way to fix this?

EDIT: I followed the guide at https://tuhdo.github.io/setup-emacs-windows.html to setup embedded browser support, so I built the linux 25.3.1 version in Cygwin.

Comment: By "window" here, do you mean window-manager window (I think so)? In Emacs that's called a "frame", which can be subdivided into *Emacs* "windows". By "Emacs 25.3 in Cygwin" do you mean a Cygwin build of Emacs or using Cygwin with a non-Cygwin build of Emacs (for MS Windows)?

Comment: By "window" I mean the win10 window, so you are right. I edited the post the clarify the Emacs version